# Why won't str_replace php function work for replacing quotes in a string passed from an array, to be used for $_GET

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to sanitize my URL, and the `GET` variable may contain a quotation mark, single or double.

```
$teststring = $row['story_title'];
$sanitized_test = str_replace("'", "~", $teststring);
echo $teststring . " versus " . $sanitized_test;
```

What this prints:

```
'''' versus ''''
```

What i expect it to print:

```
'''' versus ~~~~
```

When `$teststring = "''''";` everything works fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: what is the value $row['story_title'] is having?

Comment: @ferozakbar Does it matter? This shouldn't happen. I assume OP is not sharing the actual test case.

Comment: this is simple code and it works for me: `'''' versus ~~~~` as expected.

Comment: it is also works for me fine

Comment: It's not clear what is the expected input/output. Please edit your question.

Comment: This code simply cannot not produce the stated output. Please clarify.

Comment: @feroz the value is the same (i.e. "''''"). I am pulling it from a database. When i echo $row['story_title'] the value ( '''' ) is shown.

Comment: then it is working fine only http://ideone.com/3HdbHS

Comment: @feroz akbar The code you put in is exactly what i said works. However, when i apply the array value that is `$row['story_title']` that has the equivalent value, it doesn't work

Comment: can you print the output of print_r($row['story_title']) ?

Comment: yes. it is the equivalent value. I would show you all the code to arrive at that array value however i feel it is irrelevant. What is important is: `$teststring = $row['story_title']` and `$teststring2 = "''''";` and that `echo $teststring . " is the same as " . $teststring2;` which will print: '''' is the same as ''''

Comment: OK let me ask this way: what is a string I can use for `$teststring` that will produce the output you're getting? In other words: how do I duplicate this issue? Just tell us what `$row['story_title']` contains, exactly. Please post the output of `exit(var_dump($row['story_title']));`.

Comment: @Wesley Murch the output of is `exit(var_dump($row['story_title']));` is: string(24) "''''"    as for how i get it is a lot  of code which i feel would only serve to distract people from understanding why this is happening. Long story short, i have  a query within a function that passes the fields i would like to retrieve the data from ( hence story_title) Because the query returns multiple rows i set a while statement: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stories_data)) {$data[] = $row;}` then I am iterating through the array with a foreach loop: `foreach(array_reverse($data) as $row){blah}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, `htmlentities`. I had forgotten that for security reasons I was sanitizing the input of the data into a database with html entities, among other functions. When I was testing I just assumed to check what the value of `$row['story_title']` was by printing it, and you know what they say about assumptions.

It came to me after I made a duplicate array with the same process and it worked. Went to check my database and there it was, "`&#039;&#039;&#039;&#039;`". Oops! Essentially the issue was it wasn't finding any of the single quotes i was trying to match from that string, however when one prints that string it will show quotes.

Ultimately I changed my code to `$sanitized_test = str_replace("&#039;", "~", $row['story_id']);` and voila! It works.